# replace blank lines in php

Tags: php

How do I remove multiple blank lines from a string. 
I have looked at the examples on stackoverflow and have tried to change my code accordingly but I am not getting the right answer.

```
function removeMultipleBlankLines(&$array)
{
  $value = $array;
  $value = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $value);

  return $value;
}

  $textarray=array("The red","big","  ","  ","fox","is ready","","","to jump.");

  echo print_r(removeMultipleBlankLines($textarray));
```

Comment: I know, it didn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
$array_with_nonblank_lines = array_filter($textarray, 'trim');
```

to get exactly what you want.

Here is link to [php's docs page about `trim` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), which does the job.

Answer (score 2):

why not `$string = trim($string);`?

you can even specify what you want to be trimmed with a second optional parameter, that is `trim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )` see the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 2):

also put a trim on it:

```
   function removeMultipleBlankLines(&$array) {
      return trim(preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $array));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions works, but some people unfamiliar with regular expressions could get confused as to how you lay out your expression. Using the familiar trim command is simply a better choice in my opinion, but in the end I think trim would be faster because it doesn't need to evaluate the regular expression etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$str =preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\r\n", $str);
```

The output file will give same output on simple notepad and also on text editors eg Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through lines in a `foreach` loop and use `trim()` to handle whitespace removal. This example also loads text from a file:

```php
$lines_trim = [];
$lines = file($f, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (trim($line)) {
        $lines_trim[] = $line;
    }
}
file_put_contents($f, $lines_trim);
```

(Note: I found the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag to be unreliable, hence the need to manually remove blank lines.)

Or a super slim version:

```
$lines = file($f, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
file_put_contents($f, array_filter($lines, "trim");
```

[PHP trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) treats the following characters as "whitespace" by default:

```ini
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\v" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
$string = str_replace("\r\n",'',$string);
```