# str_replace multiple empty lines with 1 single line

Tags: php

I would like to replace multiple empty lines with one single line in php. currently I am replacing = with whitespace.

```
$message = str_replace('=', ' ', $message);
```

any suggestion on how to remove multiple {could even be 5 empty lines} with just one?

Output

```
Received On Thu, 29 May 2014 - 01:50 AM / user@test.com



= test





=
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972200/replace-blank-lines-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $message = 'Received On Thu, 29 May 2014 - 01:50 AM / user@test.com



= test





=';
echo preg_replace('/\n(\s*\n){2,}/', "\n\n", $message); // Quotes are important here.
```

OR

```
echo preg_replace('/\n(\s*\n){2,}/', "<br><br>", $message); //worked in browser
```

Comment: Can you post a sample output.?

Comment: Received On Thu, 29 May 2014 - 01:50 AM / user@test.com



= test

 


 
=

Comment: comment is not allowing me to add spaces here :(

Comment: Edit your question..:-)

Comment: ok I found my problem. I was allowing div tags. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

here is variant which replaces multiple new line symbols with any new line/space/tabs symbols after with single new line symbol:

```
$message = preg_replace('/[\r\n][\r\n\t ]*/', "\n", $message);
```

update: if you want to transform multi-line text in single line of text, you can use:

```
$message = preg_replace('/[\r\n][\r\n\t ]*/', " ", $message);
```

Comment: hi Lashane thanks for your comment. I tried it but same output.

Comment: Received On Thu, 29 May 2014 - 01:50 AM / user@test.com



= test

 


 
=

Comment: same result. I think part of my problem is I am allowing break tags  $message=strip_tags($message,"<b><br><div><p>");

Comment: can you post actual text of the message? text, not rendered html

Comment: I am using imap to MySQL, it is not allowing me to echo the body of the message only

Comment: do `echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($message).'</pre>';`

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your time, I found the problem. I was allowing <div> tags