# Remove blank from text file

Tags: php

I want to remove blank line from this text file :

```
test1
test2

test3

test4
```

So I try this code in PHP :

```
$file = __DIR__.$namefile;
foreach ($file as $k => $v) {
    if (!trim($v))
        unset($lines[$k]);
    }
    $f = fopen($file, "r");

    $array1 = array();

    //Extract all url from file
    while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
        $nl = mb_strtolower($line,'UTF-8');
        $array1[] = $nl;
    }
```

But it does not work. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace blank lines in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972200/replace-blank-lines-in-php)

Comment: Please add a more detailed description, what this code is supposed to do. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me at all...

Comment: Whould you like remove blank lines from file and save file?

Answer (score 0):

How about exploding each new line and checking if it's empty?

```
<?php
$content = fopen($file = __DIR__.$namefile, "r");
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$result = array();
foreach ($lines AS $line) {
    if (!empty($line)) {
        $result[] = $line;
    }
}
$result = implode("\n", $result);
```

Or, as Henders suggests, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7972266/1441858:

```
<?php
$content = fopen($file = __DIR__.$namefile, "r");
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$result = array_filter($lines, 'trim');
$result = implode("\n", $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = __DIR__.$namefile;
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
$result = array_filter($lines);

echo implode("\n", $result);
file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $result)); //save
```

Or use:

```
$result = array_filter($lines, 'trim');
```

If there can be whitespaces in blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = __DIR__.$namefile;
$f = fopen($file, "r");

$array1 = array();

//Extract all url from file
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
    $nl = mb_strtolower($line,'UTF-8');
    if (trim($line) != "") {
        $array1[] = $nl;
    }
}
fclose($f);
```